# Don't receive data from Subject.next()

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-formly, subject

I have an angular application using `ngx-formly`(dynamic forms) with a formly type (select) in which I have a `subscribe()`. In the component the formly form is defined with an `Observable` for the formly type and created dynamically.

In the component I have a `Subject` and buttons, producing a `next()`, the formly type does not receive the data (also didn't receive a complete).
A `subscribe()` in the component itself works.

Changing from `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject<number>()` I receive one time data in the formly type, but no further data on `next()`.

The code is meant to be used in a stepper/wizard, changing to a next step, all select's in this step should reload their options.

A 100% working stackblitz example can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ts63k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I have a good understanding of rxjs (using rxjs and ngx-store for two years; I am by far an expert), but with this I am completely stuck, so any ideas why rxjs with the same setup as in the stackblitz example is not working in my application are welcome.

- "@angular/core": "^6.1.9"
- "rxjs": "^6.3.3"
- no rxjs-compat

Comment: What do you mean by `one time data in the formly type`? In the demo when I click on `next X` it shows some output in console.

Comment: I could not reproduce your described behavior. If I replace all occurrences of `this.stepSelected$` with `this.stepSelectedXXX$` it produces the same behavior as before.

Comment: The stackblitz example is 100% working, the same setup in my application does not work, but don't find a reason why, so any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Where exactly does it not work? You should be able to use the console logs to find out. StackBlitz is good to go though once switched to `BehaviorSubject`. Maybe copy paste stackBlitz back into your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. The application makes use of dynamic forms and used cloneDeep in a service to copy the formly field definition (which was overlooked). Up till now the application used only a return of an Observable without using a Subject which worked. Now using an additional Subject things didn't work anymore, inspecting the Observable stream showed that one was closed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the architecture that you are trying to use is very similar to that of `ngrx/effects` [(Find the Github Here)](https://github.com/ngrx/effects). So now the problem with your code is that you are subscribing to the subject `stepSelected$` instead you are just piping it and applying `switchMap` operator on it. You cannot receive the value from an observable until you subscribe it.

```
this.stepSelected$.subscribe(value => {
  this.getSports(value);
});
```

You will have to do something like this to get value from the subject and then call the API.

Comment: No this is off on a tangent, the question is that formly is not subscribing to the observable passed to it. His usage of switchMap is correct. If you look at `ngOnInit` you will see his subscription usage. To my understanding problem is line 26.

Comment: The subscribe is done in core/select.type.ts (besides another subscribe in the component/ngOnInt). The stackblitz example is 100% working, press the buttons and look at the changed options. But why it does not work in my application.